# Copy files via SSH from another server ftp

Tags: ssh, ftp, passwords, copy, command

Logs in to my server via ssh. I would now like a foreign ftp server (I have a user name and password), copy all the folders that are there right on my server.
What command you use?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you recursively ftp a folder in linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113886/how-do-you-recursively-ftp-a-folder-in-linux)

Answer (score 0):

I think `scp` should serve your purpose.
[scp](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_scp.htm)

Comment: trying: scp -r LOGIN:pass@IP/folder home/my_folder
result:  Could not resolve hostname LOGIN: Name or service not known

Comment: You have to type the `ftp username` instead of `LOGIN`