# How to copy more than 5k files with FTP client from linux server

Tags: ftp, server, limit

i need to backup a site's FTP. The site is hosted on a linux server. The problem is that there is a folder with more than 5k files. Linux can't show me more than 4998 files, so i cant copy these files 'cause the server don't give me more than 4998. 
I can't delete these files to see the others 'cause the site is actually online. I can't move these file in another directory for the same reason.

What can i do? i'm trying using a shell...but i don't know...i'm not sure using this method.

Comment: Is SSH an option? Can you copy all files to a second directory, download & delete from there? Which OS runs on your client?

Comment: SSH is not an option its a web hosting and i can't have SSH access. I'm on Yosemite and i'm using Yummy FTP. I can copy ect. but i can copy only till 5k files for each folder.

Answer (score 1):

I got solution for my own answer

```
 <?php
$rootPath = realpath('wp-content/uploads/2014/07');

// Initialize archive object
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip->open('dio.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE | ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);

// Create recursive directory iterator
/** @var SplFileInfo[] $files */
$files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($rootPath),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY
);

foreach ($files as $name => $file)
{
    // Skip directories (they would be added automatically)
    if (!$file->isDir())
    {
        // Get real and relative path for current file
        $filePath = $file->getRealPath();
        $relativePath = substr($filePath, strlen($rootPath) + 1);

        // Add current file to archive
        $zip->addFile($filePath, $relativePath);
    }
}

// Zip archive will be created only after closing object
$zip->close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this through the command line, this guide [shows you how](http://tecadmin.net/download-upload-files-using-ftp-command-line/). It seems mget (the ftp command) isn't recommended for recursive calls (subfolders and their content), so wget can also be used, [se this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113886/how-do-you-recursively-ftp-a-folder-in-linux).

I also like to zip such folders with many files into one, for easy oversight when up-and-downloading. Use

```
zip -r myfiles.zip myfiles
```

Here's a [guide for that too](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57013/zip-all-files-in-directory).