# Ansible for download the files from FTP

Tags: ansible

Currently, I'm using shell script to download the files from FTP server. Ansible will execute my script and continue other automated jobs.

Please let me know the best way to do this in Ansible playbook using "get_url" instead of "shell". The following syntax is working only to download the single file but my requirements are to download the multiple files and directories.

Appreciated your help.

```
- name: FTP Download
  get_url: url=ftp://username:password@ftp.server.com/2016/03/value/myfile dest=/home/user/03/myfile1
  register: get_url_result
```

Comment: It looks like `get_url` does not support recursive download. I think `wget` is best option to download the directory/my requirements. I am using  `- shell: wget -r -np -nH --cut-dirs=1   ftp://username:password@ftp.server.com/2016/03/*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [`get_url` documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/get_url_module.html), and as far as I know, `get_url` does not support recursive download.

One possibility, as @helloV suggested, is to loop through a list with `with_items`. But this would require to have a static list of files or to obtain this list somehow, probably with `wget`.

Consequently, you could simply use `wget -m` directly in order to recursively download all files with one task. See [How to recursively download a folder via FTP on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113886/how-do-you-recursively-ftp-a-folder-in-linux).

Comment: Thank you! I will continue to use the `wget`

Answer (score 1):

Use a `list` for `urls` (or a `dict` for `urls` and `dest`) and then loop through it using `with_items`.

Give an example for few URLs and destination files.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113886/how-do-you-recursively-ftp-a-folder-in-linux

Comment: Thanks for the reply, what is the best way to download directory and sub directories from single " url:ftp.server.com" ... I am able to do using "shell: wget -r --no-parent" . Is there any options available in "get_url"