# Best practice for using Kiba as a batch process on files

Tags: kiba-etl

We'd like to run Kiba as a batch process on a series of files.  What would be the best structure to give a file mask, download the files from FTP, and then run the ETL job on each, sending a success or failure notification on a per file basis?

Is there a way to do this from within Kiba, or is the best practice just to handle all the non-ETL stuff externally, and then just call kiba on each file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would initially start with the simplest possible thing, which is like you said, using external files then calling Kiba on each one. E.g. :

- Build a rake task to download the files locally (and remove them from the FTP, or at least move them to a separate folder to avoid double-processing), inside a well-known folder which will act as an inbox. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/113900/20302) for interesting links on how to do that.
- Then build another rake task to iterate over the inbox folder and process a given file (using `Dir[pattern].each`).

Make sure to use a helper such as:

```
def system!(command)
  fail "Command #{command} failed" unless system(command)
end
```

to make sure you detect failures in execution when making system calls.

For your ETL file itself, you would use one `at_exit` block to capture failure and notify accordingly (see example here with [Bugsnag](https://docs.bugsnag.com/platforms/ruby/other/#reporting-unhandled-exceptions), and a `post_process` block to capture success and notify in that case.

This will definitely work and is simple, that said there are other possibilities, such as a single ETL file which will download files in a `pre_process` block, then have a source which will yield one filename per downloaded file, and maybe a transform which could itself call `kiba` on the command line, or even more advanced solutions.

I would stick to the simplest possible solution to get started, as always!

Comment: Thanks, at_exit looks good.  Is there any way to create something like a base class with the exit code in it, so we don't have to repeat it in every .etl file?

Comment: Typically, projects with many .etl files will indeed require a central "common.rb" boilerplate, which can either directly call at_exit, or provide a "setup" method which will itself calls at_exit. This works fairly well at a decent scale. For further modularisation you can create dedicated modules or DSL extensions, and require accordingly etc on a per-etl basis. Let me know if this is clear!

Comment: Awesome, we were already using common.rb, but didn't realize you could put your at_exit code inside there.  That works well, thanks.

Comment: Yup! It's just regular Ruby (despite the way Kiba works for the declarative syntax) - check out this article for more http://thibautbarrere.com/2015/04/05/how-to-write-solid-data-processing-code#a-different-way-to-structure-data-processing-code; finally, you may want to filter out the SystemExit exception (see http://www.bigfastblog.com/ruby-exit-exit-systemexit-and-at_exit-blunder).