# How to rewrite bash script without lftp?

Tags: bash, shell

This is the script I have, it uses the `lftp` command. How can I rewrite that script so it does the same but does not use lftp? It would be great if a standard linux tool is used.

```
#!/bin/bash
HOST=''
USER=''
PASS=''
TARGETFOLDER='/'
C_DIR=$(readlink -f .)
SOURCEFOLDER=$C_DIR'/exports'

lftp -f "
open $HOST
user $USER $PASS
lcd $SOURCEFOLDER
mirror --reverse --verbose --ignore-time --only-newer $SOURCEFOLDER         $TARGETFOLDER
bye
";
mv exports/*.xml exports/_exports_done/
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113886/how-to-recursively-download-a-folder-via-ftp-on-linux/113900#113900

Comment: I dont get it, can you point me to the solution on that post pls?

Answer (score 1):

From link provided by Michael O. comment.
[How to recursively download a folder via FTP on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113886/how-to-recursively-download-a-folder-via-ftp-on-linux/113900#113900)

```
# command to test
wget -P "$TARGETFOLDER" -r -m --user="$USER" --password="$PASS" "ftp://$HOST/$SOURCEFOLDER"
```

EDIT: because of lftp `--reverse` option, the `wget` command should be executed on target server

Comment: So where the file should be mirrored to?