# How to get folders and subfolders with specific name from in FTP

Tags: get, ftp, mget

I wish to `get` all folders and subfolders starting with string `mycobacterium` in FTP. I couldn't find any information online how to do it. I have tried `get mycobacterium*`, `mget mycobacterium*` but they don't work.

What is the right way in retrieving the data in FTP? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What FTP client are you using? What OS?

Comment: Hi Martin. I use Redhat OS and access to ftp directories using `ftp` command.

Comment: I do not think that `ftp` supports recursive file transfers. See [How to recursively download a folder via FTP on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/113886/850848).